# ocLazyLoad not allowing to execute jasmine test case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading, karma-jasmine, oclazyload

I recently added ocLazyLoad module in my app.

I am executing jasmine unit test case for home.controller.js.

In home.route.js I have following code

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', 'homeConfig', 'stateHelperServiceProvider', 
function config($stateProvider, appConfig, stateHelperService) {
    'use strict';

    $stateProvider.state(appConfig.states.base, {
        url: appConfig.rootUrl,
        data: stateHelperService.createStateData(appConfig),
        views: {
            'main': {
                controller: 'homeController',
                templateUrl: 'apps/home/home.tpl.html',
                resolve: {
                    controller: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        //Projects should be loaded first before loading home.
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load(["apps/assets/projects.bundle.js", "apps/assets/home.bundle.js"]);
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

From above code the resolve section breaking the homeController unit test cases. If i comment the resolve section then all test cases are working fine.